# Typesafe Hierarchichal Structure

Tags: scala, type-safety

I want to write an API that allows me to easily create hierarchical keys like

```
/ foo / bar / baz
```

For this I've created the following classes:

```
sealed trait Key {
  def path: String

  def /(key: String): Node = Node(this, key)
}

case object Root extends Key {
  override def path: String = ""
}

final case class Node(parent: Key, key: String) extends Key {
  override def path: String = s"${parent.path}/$key"
}
```

And it works perfectly fine:

```
Root / "foo" / "bar"
```

Now, I also want to be able to include 'placeholders' like so:

```
Root / "foo" / %
```

And this shall then return something, that when a string gets applied returns a `Key` object with the given value replaced, i.e.

```
(Root / "foo" / %)("bar") == Root / "foo" / "bar"
```

Keep in mind that this should work on n-levels, like so:

```
Root / % / "foo" / % / "bar"
```

Comment: What would `(Root / % / "foo" / % / "bar")("baz")` be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not very efficient, but it does what you asked for.

Note that, answering my own comment, I decided that

```
(Root / % / "foo" / % / "bar")("baz") == (Root / % / "foo" / "baz" / "bar")
```

but there's not much to change to have a different outcome.

```
object % // only for nicer API

trait Slashable[T <: Slashable[T]] {
  def /(key: String): T
  def /(p: %.type): PlaceHeld[T] = PlaceHeld[T](str => /(str))
}

case object Root extends Key {
  override def path: String = ""
}

sealed trait Key extends Slashable[Key] {
  def path: String

  def /(key: String): Node = Node(this, key)
}


final case class Node(parent: Key, key: String) extends Key {
  override def path: String = s"${parent.path}/$key"
}

case class PlaceHeld[T <: Slashable[T]](replace: String => T) extends Slashable[PlaceHeld[T]]{
  def /(key: String) = PlaceHeld(str => replace(str)./(key))
  def apply(key: String) = replace(key)
}
```

**EDIT**

You might want to replace your base type (without placeholders) by a simple (wrapped) `Seq`:

```
case class Key(pathSeq: Seq[String]) extends Slashable[Key] {
  def path = pathSeq.mkString("/")
  def /(key: String) = Key(pathSeq :+ key)
}

object Root extends Slashable[Root] { 
  def path = ""                       //this is because we cannot do 
  def /(key: String) = Key(Seq(key))  //Root extends Key(Seq())
}
```